# Calculate height from width to match aspect ratio

Tags: image, math, aspect

I can not figure this one out...tried alot.
I have an application that need images in aspect ratio: 56:37

I need a method that takes the width as input and returns the height that matches the aspect ratio.

Any tips? Im stuck on this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because basic math and not programming.

Answer (score 1):

In other words applying the formula is =>

**(original height / original width) x new width = new height**

Answer (score 0):

An aspect ratio of `56:37` means

`width:height = 56:37`,

or written as a division (or fraction):

`width/height = 56/37`

which can be rewritten as

`height = width*37/56`

Comment: Does this answer your question?